# How Do I Use Generic Variables for Customer Specific Data

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, entity-framework, orm

I've created a generic dll that holds commonly used variables. I have user defined fields that are place holders so we can hold customer specific data. This dll will be used in client specific apps.

How can I map these generic variables to the relevant sql table fields so that we can manipulate the custom database? I want to avoid writing custom queries.

Would an ORM like dapper be useful here?

Edit: Per danihp's reponse, I've started looking into Entity frame work. It looks promising. I'm inferring that using Fluent API I can make this dll portable into unique apps and pass a db object (instead of my class?) to do business logic.

```vb
Public Class Runs
    Private _RunMailPeices As Dictionary(Of String, MailPiece) = New Dictionary(Of String, MailPiece)
    Private _run As Integer    
    Private MailDate As DateTime
    Public Property RunMailPeices As Dictionary(Of String, MailPiece)
        Get
            RunMailPeices = _RunMailPeices
        End Get
        Set(value As Dictionary(Of String, MailPiece))
            _RunMailPeices = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property run As Integer
        Get
            run = _run
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _run = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And:

```vb
Public Class MailPiece

    Private _address1 As String = String.Empty
    Private _address2 As String = String.Empty
    Private _string1 As String = String.Empty
    Private _string2 As String = String.Empty
    Public Property Address1 As String
        Get
            Address1 = _address1
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _address1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Address2 As String
        Get
            Address2 = _address2
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _address2 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property String1 As String
        Get
            String1 = _string1
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _string1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property String2 As String
        Get
            String2 = _string2
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _string2 = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: I'm guessing you don't mean NET Generics since there is nothing related to them in that.  It seems like it would cause more work getting data into and out of the DLL for DB I/O than it saves.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. If I can do it this way, I can leverage a lot of other in house dlls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [entity framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/). You can easily map your classes to tables. You have just 2 classes related between them. Is so easy to map this classes to tables with entity framework. Then you will avoid to write queries, just LINQ expression and navigation though tables with navigation properties.

> Entity Framework (EF) is an object-relational mapper that enables .NET developers to work with relational data using domain-specific objects. It eliminates the need for most of the data-access code that developers usually need to write.

It is usual to create a Data Access Layer. *"[Entity Framework is Microsoft’s recommended data access technology for new applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx)"*

Your code looks easy to be handled by EF, but, if not, you can write new classes to easily persist your custom classes.

You can learn by example EF VB.NET code at [Entity Framework Fluent API with VB.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj631642(v=vs.113).aspx)